# Change video quality of embedded YouTube video in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, youtube

Is there a way to change the video quality when playing embedded YouTube videos in Chrome for Android? I can only change the video quality in the YouTube application.

Comment: Are you talking about changing the video quality on the fly *during* playback of a video?

Comment: I interpret this to mean the video quality of the youtube viewer in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to trigger the desktop version of the site you're looking at. After the page refreshes, you should see more options for the YouTube video.

[image]